# How to display PSU version for Weblogic 12c installation

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I cant find any way to display PSU version on a Oracle Weblogic 12c installation.

The only method is OPatch lspatches but require access to single installation.

On previous (10.3.x) the PSU version and single Patch are shown on application server log, WLST and JMX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to see versions in `WLS 12.1.2` and later (as of this date) is through `OPatch`.  See `Doc ID 1676652.1` for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can run OPatch like you mentioned:

```
opatch lsinventory
```

Or with your weblogic home set:

```
source $WL_HOME/server/bin/SetWLSEnv.sh  
java weblogic.version
```

Or from the weblogic admin console:

```
Go to the Servers link
Customize this table
Check the WebLogic Version box and add it to the right side
Click Apply
```

And when starting a server:

With 12c you should see something like `<Apr 20, 2015 4:58:52 PM UTC> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 12.1.3.0.0  Wed May 21 18:53:34 PDT 2014 1604337 >`

With 10.3 you would have also seen the same thing like `<Apr 20, 2015 5:34:42 PM UTC> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server Temporary Patch for 17069175, 17213621, 17780729 Thu Sep 11 17:27:51 MDT 2014`

Comment: But weblogic.version, weblogic admin console and weblogic log always state 12.1.3.0.0 without PSU.

Comment: What does the admin console say? Are you sure your version isn't 12.1.3.0.0 with no patches applied? Maybe your patches did not apply correctly. The above checks have worked for me on weblogic 12 with no problems - there is no change between 10 and 12 in this regard

Comment: Console display for 10.3.6 without PSU: **WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0  Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050** with 10.3.6 PSU 11 **WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0.11 PSU Patch for BUG20181997 TUE NOV 12 15:54:42 IST 2015 WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0 Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050** 12.1.3 without PSU **WebLogic Server 12.1.3.0.0 Wed May 21 18:53:34 PDT 2014 1604337** with PSU 3. So no way to distinguish between 12c with or without PSU.